# How do I make archive that is parse pointer?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

I've plan to make custom archive like boost::archive::xml_oachive and I was found good examples in boost/libs/serialization/example folder.

See next code(there is in above directory):

```
// simple_log_archive.hpp
...
class simple_log_archive
{
    ...
    template <class Archive>
    struct save_primitive
    {
        template <class T>
        static void invoke(Archive& ar, const T& t)
        {
            // streaming
        }
    };

    template <class Archive>
    struct save_only
    {
        template <class T>
        static void invoke(Archive& ar, const T& t)
        {
            boost::serialization::serialize_adl(ar, const_cast<T&>(t),
                ::boost::serialization::version<T>::value);
        }
    };

    template <class T>
    void save(const T& t)
    {
        typedef BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME boost::mpl::eval_if<boost::is_enum<T>,
            boost::mpl::identity<save_enum_type<simple_log_archive> >,
        //else
        BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME boost::mpl::eval_if<
            // if its primitive
                boost::mpl::equal_to<
                    boost::serialization::implementation_level<T>,
                    boost::mpl::int_<boost::serialization::primitive_type>
                >,
                boost::mpl::identity<save_primitive<simple_log_archive> >,
        // else
            boost::mpl::identity<save_only<simple_log_archive> >
        > >::type typex;
        typex::invoke(*this, t);
    }  
public:
    // the << operators 
    template<class T>
    simple_log_archive & operator<<(T const & t){
        m_os << ' ';
        save(t);
        return * this;
    }
    template<class T>
    simple_log_archive & operator<<(T * const t){
        m_os << " ->";
        if(NULL == t)
            m_os << " null";
        else
            *this << * t;
        return * this;
    }
    ...
};
```

Similarly, I was make my custom archive. But mine and above code is not auto casting base pointer to derived pointer. For example,

```
Base* base = new Derived;
{
    boost::archive::text_oarchive ar(std::cout);
    ar << base;// Base pointer is auto casted to derived pointer! It's fine.
}

{
    simple_log_archive ar;
    ar << base;// Base pointer is not auto casting. This is my problem.
}
```

Could you help me? How do I get from base pointer to derived pointer?

Comment: I was found a solution. simple_log_archive.hpp is just sample for basic mpl flow. If you want to make a auto castable custom archive, first, inheritance detail::common_oarchive or detail::common_iarchive and implement. Reference basic_binary/text/xml_archive. detail::common_archive already implemented a pointer casting process. 
Second, define BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Derived). This macro is make guid, this guid is used in detail::common_archive for find "true type".

Comment: Finally, I still don't know why text_oarchive is possible without register_type(), but you must register type for archive.(ar.register_type<Derived>())

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is how to convert a base class pointer to derived class then this should do it: `dynamic_cast<Derived*>(base)`.

Comment: Boost serialization have singleton type traits map. So, it's not necessity manual casting.